# 301 Redirect vs. Domain Fowarding GoDaddy

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, godaddy

I have a domain that is registered (but not hosted with GoDaddy). Previously, it used GoDaddy's domain forwarding to forward the domain to a google sites domain, but I would now like to use a 301 redirect on the domain.

**What I've Tried** - I was looking at how to make .htaccess 301 redirects, but then I noticed the following on GoDaddy when looking at the domain forwarding.
[image]

This looks as though it is using a 301 redirect. Is this sufficient to serve as a 301 redirect? Essentially, is it the same thing?

Comment: Click the Edit Button(Pencil) to have a look at the properties, then logon to your FTP Server at GoDaddyand download .htaccess from /public_html, using cPanel/FileZilla etc. and compare the 2.

Comment: The `Forward with Masking` option will maintain the `labmovement.com` URL in browsers while displaying content from `mlabpk.com`, whereas selecting `Forward only` will use a permanent `301` redirect resulting the URL also changing to `mlabpk.com`, which is desirable if you're trying to get that to be indexed by the search engines. See [this](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name?pc_split_value=1) for more.

Comment: does that mean that forward only is the technique I must use in order to have a proper 301 redirect that transfers pagerank over to mlabpk.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GoDaddy has complete instructions](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name) for using their forwarding and masking tool.

To redirect your domain to another in a way that is search engine friendly you need to select the following options:

- Redirect type: 301 (Permanent)
- Forward settings: Forward only

You have chosen "forward with masking" which uses frame redirect rather than 301 permanent redirects.   If you change the setting to "forward only", you should be fine.